# Perl JSON LWP Base64 decoded image invalid when trying to open

Tags: json, perl, http-post, uri, lwp

I'm new to LWP, URI, Base64.  I'm using LWP to post a json string containing an array from a perl script to another perl script.  One of the values in the array is a base64 encoded jpg.

I encode the image

```
open (IMAGE, "./flower.jpg") or die "$!";
$raw_string = do{ local $/ = undef; <IMAGE>; };
$encoded = encode_base64( $raw_string );
$encoded = uri_escape($encoded);
```

In the other script I decode the image and save it to a directory.  The file is slightly larger after saving it than it was originally (a couple kb larger).

```
$decoded = decode_base64($item->{'FILE'});
open my $fh, '>', "$path/flower.jpg" or die $!;
binmode $fh;
print $fh $decoded;
close $fh;
```

Also in the second script I pass the json string back and in the first script essentially print what was returned.  Everything seems to be returned/prints as expected.  When I try to open the file, I just get a standard OS message stating cannot open file.  I tried now with a pdf and a jpg. I know I'm missing something somewhere.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you missing a `uri_unescape` step?

Comment: That is what it was.  Thanks very much friend!  Buy yourself a chicken sandwich on me with your money today!